# why my second function (push2() ) not working?

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

**when i take head reference as function argument it is working but when i take head not working

where i did mistake ?
help me out

**
#c++ ============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================#

```
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;
 
 
struct node{
    int data ;
    node *link;
 
};
```

```
void push1(node** head_ref, int new_data)  
{  
   node* new_node = new node();  
   new_node->data = new_data;  
   new_node->link = (*head_ref);  

   (*head_ref) = new_node;  
}
```

```
void push2(node *head,int dat){ //it is no working ?
   
   node *new_node = new node();
   new_node->data = dat;
   new_node->link = head;
   head = new_node;


}
```

```
int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
    freopen("error.txt","w",stderr);
    #endif
 
    node *head = new node(); 
    head->data = 9;
    head ->link = NULL;
    
    push1(&head,8);
    push1(&head ,7);
    push1(&head ,6);
 
    push2(head,5); //no working ?
    node *ptr = head;
    while(ptr !=NULL){
        cout << ptr->data << " ";
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
 
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ arguments are passed *by value*. That means the value of the argument at the call-site is *copied* into the functions argument variable. If the function modifies this copied value, it will not affect the original variable or its value. Either use pointers to *emulate* pass-by-reference, or use actual references (as in `void push2(node *&head,int dat)`). Quite honestly, any decent book, tutorial or class should have information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem:

```
void push2(node *head,int dat){ //it is no working ?
```

Okay, `push2`'s first parameter is supposed to be a `node *`.

```
node *head = new node();
```

And `head` is a `node *`.

```
push1(&head,8);
```

Uhh, what? Why `&head`? If `push2` takes a `node *`, and `head` *is* a `node *`, why are you passing `&head` to `push`?

Second problem:

```
void push2(node *head,int dat){ //it is no working ?
   node *new_node = new node();
   new_node->data = dat;
   new_node->link = head;
   head = new_node; // there are two variables called 'head', which does this change?
}
```

Why are you modifying `head` right before you end the function. When the function ends, `head` no longer exists since it's local to the function. Nothing ever sees the new value.

You probably want the function to take a `node **` and pass it `&head`. Then when it modifies `*head`, it will modify `head` in the caller. You could also pass `head` by reference.

By the way, until you get more experienced, you should probably avoid giving two very different variables the same name. By calling the parameter to the function `head` and calling the pointer in `main` also `head`, you may make yourself think that changing one will change the other which, of course, it won't. They're two different variables with the same name that have different scopes.

Comment: @Karthik Don't do that. What if the next version of the code needs to have two lists? Passing `head` by reference is a simple fix.